# Unable to clone Git Repo: SSL alternative certificate error

Tags: git, gitlab

After making sure my RSA key was valid and set up properly in Gitlab, I am unable to clone a repo with HTTPS. The error being :

`fatal: unable to access 'https://[internal gitlab repo].git': SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name '(nil)`'

I could not find any info for the error when the hostname is null.
Note that the URL is correct and I can use curl to view the repo address.

This is on Windows. Cloning using SSH works initially but fails when initializing the git submodules, which might be the fault of the project configs. But I am trying to make it work using HTTPS as that is the desired workflow for the project.

I have also tried `git config --global http.sslVerify false` before the clone as a temporary workaround, to no avail.

Comment: I might be wrong... but if you have the certificates set up, you should use ssh instead of https.

Comment: I cant because of issues with git submodules with SSH on the project I'm on. We're forced to use HTTPS, which works for my coworkers, but I'm getting this cryptic error.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to clone using https because SSH was not working with submodules. However I managed to clone it successfully using `git clone --recurse-submodules [ssh path]`

The SSH method was failing because of a bug with gitkraken. Cloning it in command line now works fine, and the project opens and functions correctly in gitkraken afterwards.